# How to check condition in JavaScript with ASCII value?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm trying to do a validation for the input field and wanted to check if it's a special character or not

so I though I can check that with ASCII value but not sure how is that done in JavaScript language.

In C I can just check with the string of array right away.

```
if (input < 4 && document.myTable.inputField.value[0] < 65 )
```

I want to check if it's they have less than four character and those are special characters if yes I will give them an error message else just do nothing.

Comment: What do you want to include in "special characters"?

Comment: any special character should not be allow in the inputField so anything less than 'Dec' of 65 and greater than 122 should not be allow which is mean only a-z and A-Z only.....

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sorry if I make this question so complicated all I want to know how to actually make them accept only a-z or A-Z in JavaScript ASCII value is from 65-122 [Dec]

Comment: Well, string-to-string comparison with relational operators compares character codes: `"@" < "A" === true`, `"B" < "A" === false`. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @pimvdb I'm really sorry for making as complicated question.

What I'm trying to achieve here is that.

there should be no special character like `!@#$%^&**()_+>?|\' '` or any kind except `a-z` or `A-Z`

Comment: It's not a complicated question but "special" is a little bit ambiguous. Anyway, if it's just everything except `a-zA-Z` then a regular expression is definitely the most readable.

Comment: @pimvdb Will it be a way to avoid using Regular Expression in this condition?

Comment: @Ali: Yes, but it would be very silly to do so.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I know it will be very silly to do without using Regular Expression but it just really what I want to do but I can't really figure out how.

Comment: The reason why it would be very silly to do otherwise is that it would lead to **slower and larger code**. You really, *really* need to consider whether doing it the wrong way is actually the best choice.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams so what you is that there is no way to compare the string at position `0` if it's less than `Dec of 65` in an ASCII value and I have to compare like almost every characters? if not using regular expression?

Comment: There is. But *it's not done that way*.

Comment: Can you refer me to some site where can I find my solution or how can I find my solution in a way that I want? really sorry to disturbing you a lots :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `charCodeAt` method of String to determine the ASCII code at a certain position. Assuming that by `input` you mean the input field, this would be a way to do it:

```
var input = document.myTable.inputField.value;
if (input.length < 4 && input.charCodeAt(0) < 65 ) { /* etc. */ }
// examples charCodeAt
'foo'.charCodeAt(0);  //=> 102
'-foo'.charCodeAt(0); //=> 45
```

Comment: I just found the article about `charAt` and I check back here and it's exactly what I was asking. Thank!!

Answer (score 3):

In C, brute force checking is the cleanest and easiest alternative. In JavaScript, it is not.

```
js> /^[A-Za-z]+$/.test('foo')
true
js> /^[A-Za-z]+$/.test('bar123')
false
```

Comment: Wow, this look so complicated compare to C and C++.....

so how can I apply this in the condition of if statement? sorry to keep asking but really I'm very confuse the way how to apply this.

Comment: Same way you would as with any other condition that returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: Funny after a year I look at my own question and saw that your question would have been something that I would accept if I know about RegEx :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions. I think that's easier to read. For example: `(/a-z/gi).test(myString)` returns true if `myString` contains anything except letters (upper or lower case). So your condition can be changed to:

```
if (input < 4 && !(/a-z/gi).test(document.myTable.inputField.value))
```

Comment: is there a way without using Regular Expression?

Comment: Yes. The expression `myString.charCodeAt(0) < 65` returns true if the first character in `myString` is before the letter 'A' in the ASCII table. The function complementary to `.charCodeAt()` is `fromCharCode`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

Comment: so in my case would be like this?

`document.myTable.inputField[0] < 65 `

or did I misunderstood something?